# Is it ok to use http requests within the same web application

Tags: httpwebrequest, web-deployment

I'm designing a software system which has some C++ projects and java web applications hosted on Apache/Tomcat. Native code[C++ outputs] will connect to other systems[DB, External Gateways, etc] through web apps as **HTTP** requests. In order to make a good distributed/modular system, I'm planning to use several [5 to 10] web applications.
But still my system is not finished its developments, but function enough to sell. But even still 20% of its full features, I have to go through a huge deployment procedure since it has much of web apps.

My question is,
Is it good to merge few web apps TEMPORARILY  to reduce deployment overhead[I can do this till I get a significant larger source for each] and do http requests within that same web application?
Will it be cause any performance/memory/threading issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use a hosted JVM, which is an application on either a Servlet container or in a web service.
This way, a single JVM is re-used.
But the problem here is that, you need a communication mechanism between two applications, which I prefer of using TCP sockets.

Answer (score 1):

if you are merging two or three web components and want to deploy an single jvm
than  you should not use http request between web components,
for this you can use jboss osgi  http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/subprojects/osgi[enter link description here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/subprojects/osgi)